# How would I test a random two-dimensional array for consecutive even integers?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing this program in which a user enters the dimensions for a table, a table is then created with those dimensions and the elements within it are determined from a random generator with integers from 0 to 9. Then, what I need to do is create a loop that will determine if there are four consecutive even integers in the table.

```
2 5 8 7 1
3 2 9 4 7
5 1 2 0 3
8 0 1 2 7
```

In that table, two appear consecutively, diagonally from the first spot. It can also be like this:

```
9 5 3 7 0
2 5 7 3 1
8 5 0 2 9
4 5 1 7 5
```

In this table, five appear vertically down from the second spot.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class FourConsecutiveNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner rowDimension = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
    int firstInput = rowDimension.nextInt();

    Scanner columnDimension = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
    int secondInput = columnDimension.nextInt();

    int[][] randomTable = new int[firstInput][secondInput];
    for (int row = 0; row < firstInput; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < secondInput; column++) {
            randomTable[row][column] = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 0);
            System.out.print(randomTable[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

I know it isn't much, I have only created the two scanners and the table. I don't know how to go about creating the loop to determine the four consecutive even integers though. As I think about it, I am wondering if the way to do this is to create a nested loop that examines the first row and then the first column, then determine if either of that row or column contains the same integer four times. Then repeat that based upon the dimensions of the user input. I'm not sure though...

I know that this is the primary idea for this would be:

```
if there is x number that repeats consecutively four times in a row, then return true; else false
if there is x number that repeats consecutively four times in a column, then return true; else false
if there is x number that repeats consecutively four times in surrounding corner, then return true; else false.
```

Now, that is just pseudo-code to refer back to, but I'm seriously stumped on how I would do this and would appreciate some input from others.

Comment: Is there any particular part of the pseudo-code that's stumping you?

Comment: @CBredlow no, I know what the idea of the code is; how to implement that is what is stumping me.

Comment: If you had to do it yourself with no computer, how would you do it?  Start by just the first part (four times in a row).  Pretend you have to look through some sort of eyepiece and can only look at one number in the array at a time (so that you don't just "spot" four numbers sitting together).  You'd have to come up with some sort of method for solving this--what would it be?  I think once you figure that out, all you have to do is translate your idea to code, which you should be able to do.

Comment: P.S. An "even" number is one that is divisible by 2 (2, 4, 6, 8, ...) I don't think you meant to use that word in the title or your question--you probably meant "equal".

Comment: The best way to do this is to sit down and write out a 2d array on a piece of paper, then look at the pseudo code, and work it out in your head, writing all of the steps you did to follow that code. That will lead to the proper algorithm. From there you can go on and make the code.

Comment: @ajb you're right. I did mean to use equal. my mistake.

Comment: @CBredlow I am going to do that and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested for loop for to check in each dimension, and then, and then swap the loop counters to check the opposite.
I haven't tested this, but I think it should work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FourConsecutiveNumbers {
static boolean check_vertical(int[][] randomTable){
    for (int i =0; i<randomTable.length; i++){
        for(int t=0; t<randomTable[0].length-3;t++){
            if (randomTable[i][t]==randomTable[i][t+1] && randomTable[i][t+1]==randomTable[i][t+2] && randomTable[i][t+2]==randomTable[i][t+3]){
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
return false;
}
static boolean check_horizontal(int[][] randomTable){
    for (int i =0; i<randomTable.length; i++){
        for(int t=0; t<randomTable[0].length-3;t++){
            if (randomTable[t][i]==randomTable[t+1][i] && randomTable[t+1][i]==randomTable[t+2][i] && randomTable[t+2][i]==randomTable[t+3][i]){
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
return false;
}
static boolean check_diagonal(int[][] randomTable){
//check down    
    for (int t =0; t<randomTable.length-3; t++){
        for(int i=0; i<randomTable[0].length-3;i++){
            if (randomTable[i][t]==randomTable[i+1][t+1] && randomTable[i+1][t+1]==randomTable[i+2][t+2] && randomTable[i+2][t+2]==randomTable[i+3][t+3]){
                return true;
            }

        }



    }
//check up
    for (int t =randomTable.length; t>2; t--){
    for(int i=0; i<randomTable[0].length-3;i++){
        if (randomTable[t][i]==randomTable[t-1][i+1] && randomTable[t-1][i+1]==randomTable[t-2][i+2] && randomTable[t-2][i+2]==randomTable[t-3][i+3]){
            return true;
        }

    }
}
return false;
 }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner rowDimension = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
    int firstInput = rowDimension.nextInt();

    Scanner columnDimension = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
    int secondInput = columnDimension.nextInt();

    int[][] randomTable = new int[firstInput][secondInput];
    for (int row = 0; row < firstInput; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < secondInput; column++) {
            randomTable[row][column] = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 0);
            System.out.print(randomTable[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
   if(check_horizontal(randomTable) || check_vertical(randomTable) || check_diagonal(randomTable)){
       System.out.println("There are 4 in a row, in some way");
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("No luck");

   }
}}
```

Comment: I keep getting StringIndexOutOfBounds errors at lines 44 and 72

Comment: Ah, yes, I see my mistake. Switch -3 with -4, since the last index of an array is length-1. That should work, but again, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterating through the items in the table. For each one, if there is a matching number adjacent to it, there is the beginning of four consecutive even integers. From there, you just have to keep searcghing in the same direction.